# How to fix the connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file ///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I've added material icons to ionic2 app , and since then I get error ""The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)"" 
although the css and fonts file of MaterialIcons are in the assets folder (I've install it locally) there is no call to "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
what can I do ? Can I fix it or know why the timeout suddenly .

Comment: I also have this error using another framework (Quasar/Vue) and build a production app for Android. On my Samsung A41 this problem does not occur, but does occur on my Samsung A3

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Add   `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />`
To config.xml

Comment: Worked but i had to top the value to 100000, guess this phone is too old for this sh*t!

Comment: after adding must rebuild `ionic cordova build android`

Comment: before using that solution make sure you first try solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105757/448816 (use `--prod` flag when building project)

Comment: It works, but could you explain what ir does mean exactelly?

Comment: https://onezeronull.com/2013/08/09/increasing-loadurltimeoutvalue-to-avoid-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful-error/ check this @SlimaneMEHARZI

Answer (score 12):

Adding that **...value="70000" or "60000"** line in *config.xml* isn't the best solution and it doesn't always work nor the creation of main.html file .

I was dealing with the same issue. These two solutions did not work for me.

**SOLUTION**

-Make sure you build with

> ionic cordova build --prod **and not** 
>   ionic cordova build

-Check if one of your file or folder name doesn't contain Uppercase in it's context before building

like for example in "pages"

- templateView (instead of "templateview)

  - -templateview.ts
  - -templateview.html
  - -templateview.scss

and rename it (otherwise you will have errors)

When building finished, your app runs correctly without the "**(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)**"  error.

Answer (score 3):

As of now above solutions will work but the app will take time to load, instead of that you can simply add below in your MainActivity.java
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

In MainActivity.java you have to comment below code
loadUrl(launchUrl);

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        //loadUrl(launchUrl);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just need to also make sure that your mobile device is connected to the same wifi as your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your device version ionic not properly work on android < 4.4.4 version you could try this above 4 version 
if you want to work with 4.* version you could install cordova-crosswalk plugin

Answer (score 0):

So I added manually the following tags in config.xml right at the beginning:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<content src=“index.html” />
<content original-src=“index.html” />
```

it’s working.

Comment: That works when you are using --livereload parameter

Answer (score -1):

1- Rename your index.html to “main.html”

2- Create a new “index.html” and put the following content into it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>tittle</title>
   <script>
     window.location='./main.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

3- Rebuild your app! No more errors!

Comment: OMG what you want to achieve here? Where `main.html` is defined that it will be the first to load instead of `index.html`

Comment: I got the error net:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND for main.html

Comment: It is not working .!!!!. Application Error. FILE_NOT_FOUND Error occurs. ?

Comment: whats the point change one html page to another? it's just url that picked up in MainActivity.java!

Answer (score -6):

I add plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

then,

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android (or Run)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer. Can you provide some more details ?